# How to access data returned in MongoDB cursor in laravel controller?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

I am using Laravel 5.6 with MongoDB using [Jenssegers Package](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)

Here I want to get total count using group by a method as we do in Mysql eg.

```
select latitude,longitude,count(*) as `count` from event_logger group by latitude,longitude
```

According to docs of the package, in MongoDB we can't use aggregate functions simple as we do in eloquent but instead we have to use **raw** query with MongoDB syntax.

```
public static function getUsersByTypeLogin()
{

        $q = self::raw()->aggregate(
            [
                array(
                    '$group'=>array(
                        '_id'=>array(
                            'lat'=>'$latitude',
                            'long'=>'$longitude'
                        ),
                        'count'=>array('$sum'=>1)
                    )
                )
            ]
        );

        dd($q);
}
```

When I do dd(dump and die), I am getting `Cursor {#586}` as result.
So basically how to get/access data in cursor into my laravel application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using too this package a project. I'm using raw closure method that returns aggregation data.

For Example:

```
$data = YourModel::raw(function($collection)
{
    return $collection->aggregate(
        [
            array(
                '$group'=>array(
                    '_id'=>array(
                        'lat'=>'$latitude',
                        'long'=>'$longitude'
                    ),
                    'count'=>array('$sum'=>1)
                )
            )
        ]
    );
});
```

`$data` should be your data.

Can you try above codes?.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
foreach ($q as $row) {
    //$row contains data for every row
 }
```

where q is the cursor.